# Wire Edit lines showing over Vertex mode Edge Select?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, shortcut

[image: Incorrect]

Hey guys, I've been using blender 2.8 for a little while now and this has me stumped. The only way I can get my vertex mode to show the yellow gradient highlighting connected edges is to display edges through viewport overlay, which is not ideal. I must have hit some key or another but now the black lines projected by the Wire Edit (in user themes) is displaying OVER the yellow gradient. Any way I can get this back to default? Thanks. I like being able to see my edges.

Comment: do you mean that, in the Viewport Overlays, the Mesh Edit Mode > Edges is deactivated by default?

Comment: Edges is disabled, but I vaguely remember there being an overlay highlight on edges in vertex mode even without that option being on. is that not true anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the way to see the edges enlightened in yellow is precisely to keep the default setting, which is Viewport Overlays > Mesh Edit Mode > Edges activated